# Update SQL Server table from CSV file?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, csv

Soooooooo... I have a SQL Server table which I need to update from the contents of a csv file that I'm importing. Essentially if I have a record whose key matches the contents of Cell A, I will update one field of that record with the contents of Cell B.  From some snippets I found elsewhere, it seems I need to create a temporary table, which I have done as follows:

```
     protected void UploadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + Path.GetFileName(RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles[0].FileName);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Customer Ref", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Inventory #", typeof(string)),
           });


            string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

But I'm pretty well stumped as to where to go from here...

Any advice/suggestions/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks as always,

Paul

Comment: I don't think this is a really performant way of inserting data into SQL server... If you just need to insert data to a table from a CSV, have you tried OPENROWSET? You could then put the logic in the SP and run it from your code.

Comment: @asemprini87 not sure if I'm understanding you correctly... I'm not inserting data, only doing an update.

Comment: This sounds like a table valued parameter would be the easiest solution. You would create a user defined table type with the two columns you need. Then you load a DataTable with the values. Last but not least you create a stored procedure to receive this collection of data and perform your update. From inside the procedure you can treat the parameter just like you would any other table.

Comment: @SeanLange ... isn't that the basic idea I have above?  Never been down this road so I'm not sure I'm following precisely.  Using LINQ can I just loop through the rows in the DataTable?

Comment: That's the point. You don't need to do any looping at all. Just populate the datatable and send it to your procedure. Then your procedure can perform the update with a join. :)

Comment: @SeanLange I rarely use SP, mainly LINQ... but if I have the concept straight otherwise hopefully I can muddle my way through it :|

Answer (score 0):

So in your sample code, you have created a `DataTable` in memory (of your program, not in SQL Server), with the contents of your CSV file.  This hasn't bought you anything towards your goal.

You need to upload the data to a temp table in SQL Server, then perform an `UPDATE` statement joining your temp table to your live data.

Somewhere along the way, you will need to connect to SQL server, and execute command to create the temp table, execute a command in a loop to upload records to that temp table, execute a command with the update statement, and finally a command to drop the temp table.

Comment: So, I can't loop through the Data Table to see if I have a matching record and just update my records from that?

Comment: You really don't need loops for this. That would be the point of using a table valued parameter.